# Is there a css pseudo selector for overflow?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I'm trying to alter the style of something based on wether or not its parent div is being overflown.

```
.pDiv { display: block; width: 300px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0); }
.cDiv { display: block; padding 4px; border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
.pDiv:overflow .cDiv { border-bottom: none; }

<div class="pDiv"><div class="cDiv">child 1</div><div class="cDiv">child 2</div><div class="cDiv">child 3</div><div class="cDiv">child 4</div><div class="cDiv">child 5</div></div>
```

is it possible to do something like this? I would use the last-child pseudo-selector, but the number of children can vary, so I want it to remove the border-bottom of the last-child ONLY IF the parent div is being overflown. I want a pure CSS solution too please, no JS!

Comment: Unfortunately you'll have to use JS for this.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333379/javascript-css-check-if-overflow

Answer (score 25, accepted):

CSS cannot select based on used or computed styles of any kind, so you're out of luck.

Comment: bah, that is lame. Basically, I'm trying to eliminate having 2 bottom-borders right on top of one another when the user scrolls to the bottom of the overflown parent div. Guess I'll have to use JS, too bad there isn't a simple CSS solution :(

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII: "simple CSS solution" is an oxymoron anyway

Comment: You mean it's a Pleonasm? Sure, but it is definitely not an oxymoron.

Comment: To my knowledge, CSS can't select on used or computed styles, that's correct. But it can - in some cases - select on computed states, like :hover and :active. So I think there could be some hope that one day :overflowing might be such a selectable state. It would be mighty nice :)

Comment: @AdrianSchmidt until someone mistakenly kicks off an infinite re-render loop because their style for `:overflowing` removes the overflow and the original style re-triggers overflow... and so on.

Comment: @canon Hmm… yeah… that's true… that's not an issue with other computed states of course. And that's probably why CSS can't select on computed styles as well 

Comment: @canon wait... wait a sec... ok, I am now going to go make a infinite looping `:hover` object.

Comment: @charles-john-thompson-iii Sometimes the adjacent sibling selector can help `elm + elm { ... }`

Comment: This was discussed (and rejected) in https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2011

Comment: If you can use JS, [an `IntersectionObserver` can tell you if an element overflows](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2011#issuecomment-351779626).

Answer (score 2):

**It seems a handy solution for this is being cooked up**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Container_Queries

According to [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/next-gen-css-container/), the feature *"@container brings us the ability to style elements based on the size of their parent container."*

You should already be able to use it, but beware that **not every browser supports this yet**.

This way, you *might* (read the note) be able to get out with something like:

```
.parent-div {
    max-height: 10rem;
    overflow-y: auto;
    container: size;
}

@container (min-height: 10rem) {
    .parent-div:last-child {
        border-bottom: none;
    }
}
```

The main idea here being that if the element reached it's maximum height, then it's all but always overflowing — so we just apply the style so long as it's at it's maximum height.

Unfortunately, my own browser does not support this yet, so I can't guarantee you it would work the exact way as it is written above. But if you refer to the 2 pieces of documentation I provided, you should be able to come out on top

## Note:

The [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/next-gen-css-container/#aa-limitations) page also mentions that *"Currently, you cannot use height-based container queries, using only the block axis"*. I'm hoping this simply means using the full `size` axis is necessary in this case, but I'm not able to test this.

If someone could verify whether this solution works and then leave a comment here, that would be very much appreciated. I'd edit this answer and credit the person.