# Changing text color in div when text is truncated

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to change the text color whenever the text is truncated. But, no success yet.

In the example below, the first div (with bullet point 1) should have a different color.

Any suggestion / recommendation is appreciated.

```css
.user-comment{
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="user-comment text-truncate">1. This is a test comment. Please do not use in production.</div>
<div class="user-comment text-truncate">2. This is not a QA.</div>
<div class="user-comment text-truncate">3. No comment found.</div>
<div class="user-comment text-truncate">4. Please ignote.</div>
```

Comment: You mean the content is > 200px, you want to change the color?

Comment: I think you will need JavaScript for this.

Comment: Short answer - you need JavaScript. This looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844192/css-only-detection-of-text-overflows-in-html which deal with overflow in CSS. There are some links to JS techniques there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213197/is-there-a-css-pseudo-selector-for-overflow

Comment: @MikeGorski, sure. Thanks for the links will go through them.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a jQuery solution like this, i updated the CSS a bit in order to be able to test the width :

```js
$('.user-comment').each(function(e){
  
 if($(this).innerWidth()==200) {
    $(this).addClass('color');
 }

});
```

```css
.user-comment{
  max-width:200px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:100%;
}
.color {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="user-comment text-truncate">1. This is a test comment. Please do not use in production.</div>
<div class="user-comment text-truncate">2. This is not a QA.</div>
<div class="user-comment text-truncate">3. No comment found.</div>
<div class="user-comment text-truncate">4. Please ignote.</div>
```