# Determining the Height of an Element in Django Templates

Tags: python, html, css, django

I'm using a `div` with a fixed width, and within that `div` I have a `p` with the following CSS:

```
height:100px;
overflow:hidden;
```

I want my templates to display a `MORE` button when there is text that overflows the paragraph element and is therefore hidden. I can get a decent estimate that works 90% of the time based on how many words are in a box of a paragraph with height 100px. However, this doesn't account for things like blocks of text with a lot of short lines and line breaks. Not to mention users changing their browser's default font size. I'm less worried about the latter, but I'd really like to be able to accurately determine whether or not an element has overflow within a django template.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can use css [overflow-y](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp) property which will show a vertical scroll bar if content exceed defined height of a container e.g. div

```
overflow-y: scroll
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it requires a javascript solution.  Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333379/javascript-css-check-if-overflow) to check whether there's overflow, then you could show a hidden `MORE` button if so.

See it in action in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4fd99emg/4/)

html:

```
<p class="maybe_more">A lot of text...am I overflowing?</p>
<input class="show_more" type="submit" value="MORE">
```

css:

```
.maybe_more {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.show_more {
  display: hidden;
}
```

jQuery javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".maybe_more").each(function(){
    if ($(this)[0].scrollHeight > $(this)[0].clientHeight) {
      $(this).next(".show_more").toggle(true);
    }
  });
});
```