# Scrollbar overwrites a div

Tags: html, css

I have an issue when a scrollbar appears on a div, thanks to `overflow-y: auto;`.

When the right div `#bb` has a scrollbar (add more lines in it to see it happen), the scrollbar is over the `#help` div. **How to make this `#help` div move on the left so that it's not overwritten by the scrollbar?**

```css
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#aa {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
#bb {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
#help {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="aa" contenteditable>a
  <br>few
  <br>lines
</div>
<div id="bb" contenteditable>please add more
  <br>lines here to make
  <br>the scrollbar appear!</div>
<div id="help">?</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've changed a couple of things, I've used flexbox to get them next to each other, I've made both halves position relative. And I've put the `?` inside `#bb` and set it to position absolute.

```css
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh
}
#aa {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
#bb {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;/* Just so the bar is there */
}
#help {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div id="aa" contenteditable>a
    <br>few
    <br>lines
  </div>
  <div id="bb" contenteditable>
    I've made it always
    <br>so the scrollbar is
    <br>there but you can
    <br>change it back to auto
    <div id="help">?</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this is helpful.

**EDIT**

I've given it some thought. I think this might be a better way to do it.

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#aa {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
}
#bb {
  margin-left: 50%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
}
#help {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="aa" contenteditable>a
  <br>few
  <br>lines
</div>
<div id="bb" contenteditable>please add more
  <br>lines here to make
  <br>lines here to make
  <br>lines here to make
  <br>lines here to make
  <br>lines here to make
  <br>lines here to make
  <br>lines here to make
  <br>lines here to make
  <br>lines here to make
  <br>lines here to make
  <br>lines here to make
  <br>lines here to make
  <br>lines here to make
  <br>lines here to make
  <br>lines here to make
  <br>the scrollbar appear!
</div>
<div id="help">?</div>
```

This uses the scrolling of the body to scroll through the right column (the left column is fixed in place). This means `right:0;` will take the scroll bar into account.

Comment: Nice trick to have a scrollbar *always present* (when not needed it is disabled) so that we can place `?` at the right place once for all. But unfortunately, I don't want the scrollbar to be present when not needed...

Comment: @Basj did you read what I wrote? "I've made it always so the scrollbar is there but you can change it back to auto" The bar is just there to show it working, feel free to have it auto and it will still work :-)

Comment: Yes @AndrewBone but then the ? totally disappears when I add new lines to #bb  (at least on FF47 Windows 7)

Comment: @Basj do you mean it vanishes when you scroll down?

Comment: Yes it currently does. (But the fact of having scrollbar always present is not what we want anyway. If I move to `auto` instead of `scroll` it's the same about ? that vanishes)

Comment: I already tried similar things, but the problem is that, now, ? is part of the text. Just do CTRL+A to select all content of the editable div: then the ? will be part of it...
It seems it's very tricky to achieve what I want...

Comment: @Basj sorry pasted the wrong HTML, doesn't do that now.

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot! What was the trick? Is it the `vh` thing?  PS: you can remove the first snippet from answer. Last last thing: the blue column moves slighly on left (10 or 20px) when scrollbar appears, do you know how to fix that? Then it would be perfect :)

Comment: @Basj vh is "viewport height" it's just a more verbose way of doing 100%, the main change was using margin-left and moving the scrolling to the body rather than the div

Comment: Oh that's why the blue column #bb moves on the left when scrollbar arrives then, ok.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to set the bb div width to 48%

```css
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#aa {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
#bb2 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
#bb {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 48%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
#help {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="aa" contenteditable>a
  <br>few
  <br>lines
</div>
<div id="bb2"></div>
<div id="bb" contenteditable>please add more
  <br>lines here to make
  <br>the scrollbar appear!</div>
<div id="help">?</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but it breaks a bit the usual user experience of having a scrollbar touching the right boundary of the screen...

Comment: I found a javascript function in this post --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333379/javascript-css-check-if-overflow
check this out.

Comment: or I thouht about a trick, set a second empty div under the 'bb', but with full  50% width and also a blue background, it should to the job.

Comment: The problem @linearSpin is that is not an event, so I won't be able to know when this happen...

Comment: It's the same @linearSpin : the scrollbar is not close to the boundary of the screen, this breaks the user experience standards...

Comment: Nobody can help You, becouse you did not gave us a proper quesiton. 
But here is the point: You make a mistake on very begining, the help 'div' should not be inside the 'bb'.  Just make a button outside.