# How to make a method that will trigger at the event of overflow?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a dynamic table in .html that reads the data from the database to display all the elements, and they can obviously fall out of bounds when they reach certain amout.

I don't want to use scrollbar, but instead I want a box to appear if there are elements out of view, just to make it clear that you can still access them despite the lack of scrollbar.

Is there some Angular functionality that can help me with that?

Comment: I do not think there is any specific Angular functionality that let's you do this, but you can do it with JavaScript, like suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333379/check-if-an-elements-content-is-overflowing
The you can use an *ngIf to hide / show your box