# How to remove scroll bar from embedded Calendly schedule?

Tags: html, css, calendly

I have embedded a calendly scheduler into my html, css website however it includes its own scroll bar which creates issues for the website functionality. How do I go about removing the scroll bar?

**Calendly Embedded Code**

```
  <!-- Calendly inline widget begin -->
  <div class="calendly-inline-widget" data-url="https://calendly.com/kumaladevelopment/60min" style="min-width:320px;height:630px;"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js" async></script>
  <!-- Calendly inline widget end -->
```

[image]

Comment: https://help.calendly.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019861794-Common-embed-questions#3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
<div class="calendly-inline-widget" data-url="https://calendly.com/kumaladevelopment/60min" style="min-width:320px;height:630px;"></div>
```

to

```
<div class="calendly-inline-widget" data-url="https://calendly.com/kumaladevelopment/60min" style="min-width:320px;height:650px;"></div>
```

I've tried adding overflow:hidden which doesn't seem to work which is a PITA. Just adding 20px to the height seems to work okay though. You could do a bit of JS to check if the contents were overflowing the div and adjust the height to suit like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333379/check-if-an-elements-content-is-overflowing)

Comment: I tried that and it ended up working. Seems like something weird with Calendly's code on their side with the height. Thank you for the help it was driving me crazy trying to hide the overflow-y and having it not work lol.

Comment: For me increasing height did not help. The calendly content is always some pixels bigger than the div.calendly-inline-widget. Problems seems not to happen, if you use portrait orientation or just a mobile with a wider screen.

Answer (score 3):

Calendly suggests in their docs the container (height) is to small for the widget.

The docs suggest increasing height to `750px`:

```html
<div class="calendly-inline-widget" data-url="https://calendly.com/YOUR_EVENT" style="min-width:320px;height:750px;"></div>
```

https://help.calendly.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019861794-Common-embed-questions#3

Answer (score 3):

If you use Popup Text widget and not inline widget, here is the solution working on my side:
The tips was to increase the default height of the wrapper .calendly-popup from 680px to 690px.

```html
<link href="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js" type="text/javascript" async></script>

<style>.calendly-overlay .calendly-popup {max-height: 690px;}</style>

<a href="" onclick="Calendly.initPopupWidget({url: 'https://calendly.com/xxx/yyy?hide_event_type_details=1&hide_gdpr_banner=1'});return false;">
Book a meeting
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the CSS code below in the additional CSS :

```
.calendly-inline-widget iframe {
height: 1000px !important;
}
```

it will fix all the scrolling issues on desktops, tablets & from mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Add this css style:

```
.calendly-inline-widget {
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have solved with the **lnline embed code** from calendly for a while.
so finally I changed to use **table and iframe** to fixed the scroll bar with mobile like this

copy link from calendly that you use.

https://calendly.com/kumaladevelopment/60min

add the link to this code

```html
<!-- Calendly iframe begin -->
<style>
* { margin:0 padding:0 }
body { margin:0; padding:0; text-align:center }  
#hold_iframe { padding:0px; margin:0 auto; width:100%; height:2000px }
</style>
<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 id="hold_iframe">
    <iframe src="https://calendly.com/kumaladevelopment/60min" 
width=100% height=2000 marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 frameborder=0></iframe>
</table>
<!-- Calendly iframe end -->
```

I adjust the height to 2000px because when you select the time , that very long.
You can adjust this code by yourself with your page.

Answer (score -2):

Add the following to your embed code.

overflow:hidden;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).