# materializecss: tabs with pagination (or indicator there is more)

Tags: materialize

Following this: https://materializecss.github.io/materialize/tabs.html there is horizontal scrolling if the number of tabs exceeds the horizontal space.

However, is there a way to indicate this to user besides the horizontal scroll bars?

Comment: Assuming this is mostly a design related question, you might be able to get an answer on [UX StackExchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

A simple and pure CSS solution would be to use `background-attachment: local`, which would display a simple image (a gradient in this case):

[image: Example for CSS background attachment]

And yes, there are some other ways using javascript for this task (you can find examples including the CSS solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333379/check-if-an-elements-content-is-overflowing)) but they may lag and cost performance.

### Example for `background-attachment: local`:

The Tutorial: https://lea.verou.me/2012/04/background-attachment-local/
And the Code for it: https://dabblet.com/gist/2462915

```css
/**
 * Scrolling shadows by @kizmarh and @leaverou
 * Only works in browsers supporting background-attachment: local; & CSS gradients
 * Degrades gracefully
 */

html {
    background: white;
    font: 120% sans-serif;
}

.scrollbox {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    margin: 15px auto;

    background:
        /* Shadow covers */
        linear-gradient(white 30%, rgba(255,255,255,0)),
        linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0), white 70%) 0 100%,
        
        /* Shadows */
        radial-gradient(50% 0, farthest-side, rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,0)),
        radial-gradient(50% 100%,farthest-side, rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,0)) 0 100%;
    background:
        /* Shadow covers */
        linear-gradient(white 30%, rgba(255,255,255,0)),
        linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0), white 70%) 0 100%,
        
        /* Shadows */
        radial-gradient(farthest-side at 50% 0, rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,0)),
        radial-gradient(farthest-side at 50% 100%, rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,0)) 0 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: white;
    background-size: 100% 40px, 100% 40px, 100% 14px, 100% 14px;
    
    /* Opera doesn't support this in the shorthand */
    background-attachment: local, local, scroll, scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollbox">
    <ul>
        <li>Not enough content to scroll</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
    </ul>
</div>


<div class="scrollbox">
    <ul>
        <li>Ah! Scroll below!</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
        <li>9</li>
        <li>10</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
        <li>9</li>
        <li>10</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
        <li>The end!</li>
        <li>No shadow there.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

(And by the way, you can even [modify the scrollbar](https://www.w3schools.com/HOWTO/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp) if you want to.)