# show more option using mui chip from selected values in grid (expand/collapse)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-x

Using React Mui data grid, I am displaying selected values from the **DataGrid** to the top section. Chip is being used to display selected values in the top section. In this section, there is a functionality that allows the view to display **"+1 More"** options if there is not enough space. By clicking **More** Chips, other values are displayed and the button will be changed to **"Hide"**. Despite implementing functionality, it appears to not be working fully as expected. So basically when I start selection from grid with 2dn or 3rd selection it should display "More" option but seems it showing after 4th row. Please click on fiddle to see the issue [fiddle](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jdxk2u?file=Demo.tsx)

> When **+ More** option visible

[image]

> With **Hide** option visible
> [image]

Here I have crated an working [fiddle](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jdxk2u?file=Demo.tsx)

**Code snapshot**

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { DataGrid, GridRowSelectionModel } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import { useDemoData } from '@mui/x-data-grid-generator';
import { Stack } from '@mui/material';
import Selections from './Selections';

export default function DisableClickSelectionGrid() {
  const { data } = useDemoData({
    dataSet: 'Commodity',
    rowLength: 10,
    maxColumns: 6,
  });
  const [rowSelectionModel, setRowSelectionModel] =
    React.useState<GridRowSelectionModel>([]);

  const onDelete = (item: any) =>
    setRowSelectionModel((prevState) =>
      prevState.filter((id) => id !== item.id)
    );

  const onClear = () => setRowSelectionModel([]);
  return (
    <Stack sx={{ height: 500, width: '100%' }}>
      {!!rowSelectionModel.length && (
        <Selections
          {...{ onDelete, onClear }}
          values={rowSelectionModel.map((id) =>
            data.rows.find((item) => item.id === id)
          )}
        />
      )}
      <DataGrid
        checkboxSelection
        onRowSelectionModelChange={(newRowSelectionModel) => {
          setRowSelectionModel(newRowSelectionModel);
        }}
        rowSelectionModel={rowSelectionModel}
        {...data}
      />
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

Here below code, I have created a selection that will display the chips. In order to display the Show More option, I am employing the following function that will give me the index that has been wrapped (since I am using a flexbox CSS modal).

```js
const isWrapping = (el: any) =>
  el.previousElementSibling &&
  el.offsetLeft < el.previousElementSibling.offsetLeft;

const getWrappingElementsIndex = (container: any) => {
  let index = Infinity;
  for (let i = 0; i < container?.children?.length; i++) {
    if (isWrapping(container.children[i])) {
      index = i - 1;
      break;
    }
  }

  return index;
};
```

The selection values are being divided into two arrays based on the wrapped index.

```js
const useSelection = (values: any) => {
  const [expand, setExpand] = useState(false);
  const [hasScroll, setHasScroll] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState({ firstRow: values, restValues: [] });
  const ref = useRef<any>(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const visibleElementIndex = getWrappingElementsIndex(ref.current);
    console.warn('visibleElementIndex', visibleElementIndex);
    setData({
      firstRow: values.slice(0, visibleElementIndex),
      restValues: values.slice(visibleElementIndex),
    });
    setHasScroll(ref.current?.scrollHeight > SelectionMaxHeight);
  }, [values.length]);

  const onExpand = () => setExpand((prevState) => !prevState);

  return { expand, onExpand, data, ref, hasScroll };
};
```

I would be grateful for any assistance. Thank you in advance

Comment: You say "it appears to not be working fully as expected", but I can't see that you ask a precise question. Which part doesn't work? From the second screenshot, it seems to work quite well?

Comment: I edited question, So basically when I start selection from grid with 2dn or 3rd selection it should display "More" option but seems it showing after 4th row. Please click on fiddle to see the issue [fiddle](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jdxk2u?file=Demo.tsx)

Comment: Could you possibly just check if the containing element is overflowing? [Possible source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333379). And a ResizeListener to make sure it checks every time it's resized.